# terminal starts with: bash: source/opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash: No such file or directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 and ros fuerte version 1.8.10. When I type the command "rosversion ros", the terminal returns the version as 1.8.10.
But each time I start the terminal, it shows
"bash: source/opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash: No such file or directory"
in the very first line. What is the problem ??? :\

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43602/terminal-starts-with:-bash:-source/opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [ans.10010](https://answers.ros.org/users/3187/ans.10010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you have a line

```
source/opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
```

somewhere at the end of your ~/.bashrc file. Note that there is a space missing after the `source`, i.e. the line should be:

```
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
```

Open ~/.bashrc and fix the line.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3